# How can I check if a publishing page exists before creating it by code in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I got this code

```
PublishingPage newPage = pWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(fileName, layout);
                        newPage.Title = title;
```

However if the page exists it throws an exception and I want to check easily if it exists before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this :

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
foreach (PublishingPage page in pWeb.GetPublishingPages())
{
    if (page.Name.Equals("myPage.aspx"))
    {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Or if you find it's not fast enough you could try this:

```
pWeb.GetPublishingPages().ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(filename))
```

Comment: isnt there a faster way? what about if there are 1000 pages, doesnt loook very fast to iterate over all of them, maybe an SPQUery?

Comment: great, looks better, will try it